# How to Process in XML format response using SAX parser in Android

Tags: android, soap, xml-parsing, saxparser, domparser

I have tried one xml string response using SAX parser. I am receiving the tag names only in Logs: `OtpResponse`, `return`, `Resp`, `TssId`, etc....

I want the tag outputs only.. and am getting tag names only..

My Sample Program :

My Sample XML Format :
http://textuploader.com/5ezjf

Appreciate, if the above xml format processing sample program suggest.
Anyone help to get solution..

Comment: Please format your code and add markup

Comment: do you want dom sample or sax sample? or you are open to third party apis?

Comment: thank you for reply..I have already tried with sample Sax parser example.But, i could not process the above mentioned xml format. if possible, suggest any program for above mentioned xml response process..

Comment: Where is your code? It is missing from your post.